# Is Vim reading my html.vim file when I open a Markdown file?

Tags: vim

I have a file ~/.vim/ftplug/markdown.vim that contains these directives:

```
    setlocal tabstop=4
    setlocal shiftwidth=4
    setlocal softtabstop=4
    setlocal expandtab
```

I also have an html.vim file that contains these directives:

```
    setlocal tabstop=2
    setlocal shiftwidth=2
    setlocal softtabstop=2
    setlocal expandtab
```

I'm finding that whenever I edit a .md file, I can do ":set sw=?" and see that it's set to 2, not 4, as I would expect.  This holds true for the other settings as well.  I suspect that Vim is also reading my html.vim file when I open a markdown file.  Is that what's happening?  And if it is, is there any way I can tell Vim to just read the markdown.vim file and ignore the html.vim file whenever I open a .md file?

Comment: You should put `markdown.vim` under `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` and not `~/.vim/ftplug`. To check where `sw` was last set you can do `:verbose set sw`. Reading `:help ftplugin` may help fix the problem

Comment: Thanks @Sergio.  That appears to have resolved the problem.  If you want to change your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the markdown filetype plugin script (`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim`) sources (kind of "inherits from") the html filetype, presumably because Markdown allows inline HTML.

In order to customize stuff like indent settings, put your commands into the *after directory*; i.e. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`. As these follow later in the `'runtimepath'`, they are read last, and therefore can override the default settings.